# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module React-Native

Tags: react-native, jtest

[image]

Hello everyone I hope you're doing okey , I had this problem with googlesignin , I did mock it , then problem with firebase again did mock it , now Im getting this error and I can't find any solution for it

Answer (score 1):

I believe adding a `transformIgnorePatterns` to your jest config file will solve your problem.

```
transformIgnorePatterns: [
"node_modules/(?!(react-native-root-siblings|react-native|my-project|react-native-button)/)",
  ],
```

https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#transformignorepatterns-arraystring
https://jestjs.io/docs/tutorial-react-native#transformignorepatterns-customization

Comment: type ErrorHandler = (error: mixed, isFatal: boolean) => void;
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Answer (score 0):

[image]

this is weird , I can't find a proper solution , I did try different transformignorePatterns

Comment: Try with the one I added, you have to add all the packages that are in conflicts

Comment: Same problem sadly